# Mailx command sending blank spaces in mail

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, mailx

I have to get a person name from logs and use that information for sending mail. I am using below awk command to retrieve person name from logs.

log:

```
person name: Harry
```

Harry is the last word in that line. cursor is at the end of Harry.

command used:

```
person_nm=`grep 'person name:' /log | awk '{print $3}'`
```

I am using the below command to send mail

```
echo "$person_nm - congrats" | mailx -r xyz@abc.com -s "message"
```

My expected result in mail is

```
Harry - congrats
```

but what I am getting is Harry in one line and Hyphen congrats in next line

Harry

-congrats

when I give the same echo command in my Unix environment(Korn shell script), result is getting displayed in a single line but the same is not sent in a mail. Is there something wrong with the awk command or issue is with mailx? Please help me.

Comment: Your `grep` will never match because it doesn't match the capitalization of the string in `log`.  Even if it did match, that command line would return `This`, because you're asking `awk` for `$3`, which is the third whitespace-delimited field.  Please include functional code in your question and the *actual* output it produces.

Comment: edited the question. I cannot copy the exact code, so i have provided some sample data.